# SQL Server Amount "Open" At Each Month End

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a query that will sum the `Amount` of Open Accounts Receivable for each month.

Each record in my table has `Amount`,`Posting Date`, and `Closed at Date`.  So for example, one record might be: `Amount : 5000`, `Posting Date : 1/1/15`, `Closed at Date : 3/5/15`.  So for this record, the 5000 would need to be added to my January Open AR calculation because it is open as of 1/31/15, added to my February Open AR calculation because it is open as of 2/28/15, but excluded from my March Open AR calculation because it is closed as of 3/31/15.

I have managed to create a query that will work for an individual month, given a single inputted month-end date, i.e. 1/31/15 or 2/28/15, etc..., which goes into the WHERE clause.

`SELECT SUM(Amount), threemonthavg, SUM(Amount)/threemonthavg AS DSO
FROM tbl1
WHERE PostDate <= @enddate AND ClosedDate > @enddate`

Am I on the right track to expand this out to include each month in one query or would I be better off taking what I have, and creating a stored procedure to run this query for each month and union the results together?

Comment: where does the `threemonthavg` column comes from?

Comment: I would expand the query to GROUP BY month, and include any date range that you want.

Comment: If you need to do calculations related to dates, I would create a date table, and you could join that to your table -- and calculate for example this without looping

Comment: `group by year(datefield), month(datefield) where datefield between 'start time' and 'end time'`, basically.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the threemonthavg is a separately calculated field that doesn't depend on the PostDate or ClosedDate.

Comment: @JamesZ, I like the idea of a separate date table, and I have one already built, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I would perform the join for items that are open for multiple months.

Comment: You can just use the table same way, just do the join on "PostDate <= datecolumn AND ClosedDate > datecolumn" and of course limit the date table so that you only include the last day of month

Comment: @JamesZ Thank you! That worked perfectly. I can't tell you how much time I wasted trying to figure this solution out.